# I do not understand, nor how to fix this error of failed constraints in sql

Tags: php, mysql, web

So my Error is :

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inb_201`.`notes`, CONSTRAINT `fk_notes_staff1` FOREIGN KEY (`staff_staffID`) REFERENCES `staff` (`staffID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I'm not too sure what it means, and i do not know how to fix this exactly... first time I've seen this!

Comment: Maybe there is not entry in staff with the given id

Comment: You're trying to add a row to  a child table that doesn't have a corresponding entry in the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

The table on wich you trying insert has a foreign key and you're not providing this key in insert.

There are some important things to remember when inserting data into tables with referential constraints. If you are inserting data into a parent table with a parent key, SQL does not allow:

Duplicate values for the parent key.

If the parent key is a primary key, a null value for any column of the primary key

If you are inserting data into a dependent table with foreign keys:

Each non-null value you insert into a foreign key column must be equal to some value in the corresponding parent key of the parent table.

If any column in the foreign key is null, the entire foreign key is considered null.

If all foreign keys that contain the column are null, the INSERT succeeds (as long as there are no unique index violations).